# Extract specific characters from each line

Tags: text-processing, awk, perl

I have a text file, and I want extract the string from each line coming after `"OS="`

```
input file line
A0A0A9PBI3_ARUDO Uncharacterized protein OS=Arundo donax OX=35708 PE=4 SV=1
K3Y356_SETIT ATP-dependent DNA helicase OS=Setaria italica OX=4555 PE=3 SV=1
```

Output desired

```
OS=Arundo donax
OS=Setaria italica
```

OR

```
Arundo donax
Setaria italica
```

Comment: Are there always 2 words to print after `OS=` or do you want all words between `OS=` and `OX=`?

Comment: i need only two words

Comment: This is a work order, not a question. No demonstrated effort.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use GNU `grep` (or compatible) with extended regex:

```
grep -Eo "OS=\w+ \w+" file
```

or basic regex (you need to escape `+`

```
grep -o "OS=\w\+ \w\+" file
# or
grep -o "OS=\w* \w*" file
```

To get everything from `OS=` up to `OX=` you can use `grep` with perl-compatible regex (PCRE) (`-P` option) if available and make lookahead:

```
grep -Po "OS=.*(?=OX=)" file

#to also leave out "OS="
#use lookbehind
grep -Po "(?<=OS=).*(?=OX=)" file
#or Keep-out \K
grep -Po "OS=\K.*(?=OX=)" file
```

or use `grep` including `OX=` and remove it with `sed` afterwards:

```
grep -o "OS=.*\( OX=\)" file | sed 's/ OX=$//'
```

Output:

```
OS=Arundo donax
OS=Setaria italica
```

Answer (score 4):

In Perl, two non-whitespace "words":

```
$ perl -lne 'print $1 if /OS=(\S+ \S+)/' input
```

or everything up to `OX=`:

```
$ perl -lne 'print $1 if /OS=(.*?) OX=/' input
```

or everything up to the next `something=`:

```
$ perl -lne 'print $1 if /OS=(.*?) (\w+)=/' input
```

With your sample input, they all give the same output, but the output would be different with e.g. an input like this:

```
ABC=something here OS=foo bar doo PE=3 OX=1234
```

Answer (score 3):

A more robust way is to use sed to parse the full value until the word containing the next = is found. That way it will work on any sized value (e.g. if you have a font with one word or three words).

```
sed 's/.*OS=\([^=]*\).*/\1/;s/ [^ ]*$//'
```

The first block grabs everything up to `OS=`, the second block in the capture group (denoted by `\(\)`'s) matches upto the next `=` and can be referred to in the replacement as `\1`. The next substitution rids the last word which is a fragment from the next assignment.

Note: the `^` in `[]`'s is to exclude match the character in this case everything that is *not* an `=` sign.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print $(NF-4), $(NF-3)}' file

OS=Arundo donax
OS=Setaria italica
```

or

```
awk -F= '{sub(/OX/,""); print $(NF-3)}' file 

Arundo donax 
Setaria italica
```